# C# problem with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like this :

```
string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit [1] amet, [3] consectetuer adipiscing  [5/4/9] elit  
Ut odio. Nam sed est. Nam a risus et est[55/12/33/4] iaculis";
```

I want to get a **list of string** with all [digit] or all [digit/digit/...] present in my text.

For example:

```
{"[1]","[3]","[5/4/9]","[55/12/33/4]"}
```

for the text above.

How can I do that with regex?

Comment: With regexes, it pays to heed the age-old advice in the spirit of your text: *Omnia licent sed non omnia ædificant.* ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\[[\d/]*\]");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[     # match a literal [
[\d/]* # match any number of digits or /
\]     # match a literal ]
```

Comment: Why not use `Matches()` instead of `Match()`?

Comment: to get all ocurences of my patern

Answer (score 3):

Get the matches as a collection, and get the value from each match into an array like this:

```
string[] items =
  Regex.Matches(text, @"\[([\d/]+)\]")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
  .ToArray();
```

For simplicity the pattern matches anything that is digits and slashes between brackets, so it would also match something like `[//42/]`. If you need it to match only the exact occurances, you would need the more complicated pattern `@"\[(\d+(?:/\d+)*)\]"`.

#### Edit:

Here is a version that works with framework 2.0.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"\[([\d/]+)\]")) {
  items.Add(m.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: it seem very good can you explain me the real difference of the Tim's answer?

Comment: @Christophe Debove: I use the `Matches` method to get all matches in a single call, then I use the `Select` method to get the value out from each of the matches.

Comment: I've just close visual studio but I will try it tomorow thanks

Comment: @Guffa Hi, it say Error 1 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), surely because I'm working on v2 on runtime

Comment: @Christophe Debove: You need to target framework 3.5 or later and have a `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file for this to work.

Comment: @Guffa hahaha yes I know, but I can't. :P      All the projet I need to implement that function is under 2.0 lol

Comment: @Christophe Debove: I added a version for framework 2.0 above.

Answer (score 1):

```
string regex = @"(\[[\d/]*?\])";
```

Comment: No need for a lazy quantifier or for capturing parentheses. And you should probably use a verbatim string.

Comment: True, there is no need for one, but I'd rather have one and not use it in contrast to not having one and forgetting to put it when I should change the expression.

Comment: I'm sorry, why the downvote? It wasn't clear he wanted the full C# code, he asked about regex, and that's what I gave him.

Comment: @Femaref the question was not only what is the regex I need, but how to get a list of string (it's in bold) with regex

Comment: Oh, okay. Didn't catch that then.

Comment: That won't even compile.  You either have to use a verbatim string as @Tim said, or double all those backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input string is stored in a variable `input`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\[(\\d/?)*\\]");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);
```

`MatchCollection matches` holds all of the matches and can be displayed like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Value);
```

The above loop outputs:

```
[1]
[3]
[5/4/9]
[55/12/33/4]
```